# Error thrown when executing chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on my first extension and am trying to create a simple extension to inject a draggable div on a page.  That works nicely, but I want to preserve the location of the div on the background page (I'm also trying out local storage, but want to understand why this isn't working).

I do not need a button so have not created a popup.html file, which, I believe, is entirely optional.  It certainly has worked so far just injecting javascript files.

However, I now get the following error thrown when executing chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage():

Uncaught Error: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more details.

The content scripts documentation did not seem to identify anything wrong with my approach: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Here is a redacted manifest I am using:

```
{
"name": "My helper",
"version": "1.0", 
"description": "Tastes great",
"background_page": "background.html",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches":["https://page.of.interest/*"],
        "run_at":"document_idle",
        "js":[ "jquery.js", "jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js", "my_content_script.js"],
        "css": [ "my_content_script.css" ]
    }
],
"permissions": [
  "background"
] 
}
```

So I am running this statement inside "my_content_script.js".  Is this NOT considered part of the extension process?  Can I only run this on a popup.html (or other possibly?) file?

If this is the case, then maybe it is easier to just use localstorage rather than trying to communicate through the dom with the extension process.

Hope I've been clear despite my ignorance about some of these concepts.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the docs explicitly say you can't use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` from a `content_script` but because the `content_script` has permissions more oriented with the page it is being run on it isn't allowed access. The [docs do mention](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#content_scripts) a few methods you can use however.

> Unlike the other chrome.* APIs, parts of chrome.extension can be used by content scripts:

You will have to use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to communicate between the `background_page` and the `content_script`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the **chrome.cookies.get()** in **background.html**, and then do the **communication** between your **content script** and **background.html** for exchanging cookie data.